# Tensorflow dataset api

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am reading CSV file using `tf.contrib.data.make_csv_dataset(csv_path)`, the CSV has 2 columns namely ***review*** and ***rating***. What I want to perform tokenization on review column after reading .

```
 dataset = tf.contrib.data.make_csv_dataset(csv_file, batch_size=2)
```

After creating dataset, I want my map below method to dataset for ***review*** column:

```
def create_tokens(sentence):
    return tf.string_split([sentence).values
```

I am stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this example data:

```
review, rating
Best film ever, 5
rather meh, 2
```

You should be able to use tf.data.map() as explained [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets) and [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map) in tensorflow 1.10:

```
def create_tokens(sentence):
    return tf.string_split(sentence['review'])

dataset = tf.contrib.data.make_csv_dataset('test.csv', batch_size=2)
dataset = dataset.map(create_tokens)
```

Comment: Did the same thing but getting below error
TypeError: Expected string, got {'overall': <tf.Tensor 'arg0:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>, 'reviewText': <tf.Tensor 'arg1:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>} of type 'dict' instead.

Comment: problem I am facing is that dataset contains 2 columns as dictionary and map function is unable to map the reviewText column to create_tokens method

Comment: could you try to parse the dict in the function: 
tf.string_split([sentence['reviewText']).values

Comment: Tried and got this error ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'StringSplit' (op: 'StringSplit') with input shapes: [1,?], [].

Comment: I've added example data above which works for me in TF 1.10. Is this how your data looks like? Also, have you considered using: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer or another tokenizer?

Comment: can you please take a look on another issue I am facing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52178422/i-am-getting-lookup-table-not-initialized-error-when-looking-up-the-table?noredirect=1#comment91307222_52178422

Comment: Done, and Thanks for looking into my other problem